# base64_encode returns blank space before string

Tags: php, base64

I'm using a site called ViaPost to post letters for my business. I'm using the SoapClient. The uploaded file must be in the base64binary format. I'm using the following code however returns empty.

```
    $pdf_data = file_get_contents('test.pdf'); 
    $pdf_data = base64_encode($pdf_data);
    print $pdf_data;
```

To expand on the above:

```
    POST /viapostcustomer.asmx HTTP/1.1
    Host: api.viapost.com
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: length
    SOAPAction: "http://api.viapost.com/CreateLetter"





    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <CreateLetter xmlns="http://api.viapost.com">
          <loginToken>string</loginToken>
          <name>string</name>
          <description>string</description>
          <FileContents>base64Binary</FileContents>
          <dynamic>boolean</dynamic>
          <shareLetterWithGroup>boolean</shareLetterWithGroup>
          <returnMessage>string</returnMessage>
          <letterID>long</letterID>
        </CreateLetter>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>


    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: length

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <CreateLetterResponse xmlns="http://api.viapost.com">
          <CreateLetterResult>boolean</CreateLetterResult>
          <returnMessage>string</returnMessage>
          <letterID>long</letterID>
        </CreateLetterResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>


    <?php
    $client = new SoapClient("http://api.viapost.com/viapostcustomer.asmx?WSDL");
    $params = array('sUserName'=>'USERNAME','sPassword'=>'PASSWORD','sLoginToken'=>'','sReturnMessage'=>'');
    $SignIn = $client->__soapCall('SignIn', array($params));
    $sLoginToken = $SignIn->sLoginToken;


    $pdf_data = file_get_contents('test.pdf');
    $pdf_data = base64_encode($pdf_data);
    $params = array('loginToken'=>$sLoginToken,'name'=>'testname','description'=>'testdescription','fileContents'=>$pdf_data,'dynamic'=>'true','shareLetterWithGroup'=>'false','returnMessage'=>'','letterID'=>'');
    $CreateLetter = $client->__soapCall('CreateLetter', array($params));
    $returnMessage = $CreateLetter->returnMessage;
    print $returnMessage;


    ?>
```

it returns: There was a problem saving your file. Please try again.

I've done something daft I know I have.

Comment: Is `$pdf_data` empty? (Does `file_get_contents('test.pdf');` return valid data?)

Comment: Has your $pdf_data variable content before base64_encode?

Comment: yes it does. this is what I don't get. I will admit I've never used either of the two commands before. Is base64_encode printable? thanks for the reply

Comment: What does `var_dump(realpath('test.pdf'))` output?

Comment: I've done the var_dump the file is correct. I've got to the stage where I have a readable string through print now but the string has aleast 300 blank characters before it. The soap returns... was a problem saving your file. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

`base64_encode` will return empty string if the passed argument is itself empty. You should check this before you pass data to this function.

```
if(strlen($pdf_data)>0){
   $pdf_data = base64_encode($pdf_data);
}else{
   throw new Exception("Empty File provided");
}
```

Comment: the file isn't empty, my mistake as the output has hundreds of black spaces before it. I dont understand? Surely the base64_encode should start from character one.

Comment: Those blank lines were generated by code above this print statement. Show your complete code and hopefully we'll figure it out.

Comment: Thank you. Ive added my code. I'm encoded and then decoded the file and it returns normally. Starting to wonder if its suppose to have the white space before it. But the SOAP response still fails. I've tried other SOAP calls to ViaPost and they work. This is the main reason I was looking at the encoding.

Comment: Does your file contain those SOAP headers and responses?

Comment: Ive added everything to the post. `$params = array('loginToken'=>$sLoginToken,'name'=>'testname','description'=>'testdescription','fileContents'=>$pdf_data,'dynamic'=>'true','shareLetterWithGroup'=>'false','returnMessage'=>'','letterID'=>'');`

Comment: The online manual for ViaPost doesn't exist and support is limited. I think this is wayyyyy post my programming knowledge. I'm electrician by trade do this for a hobby. This was gonna be for my online invoicing you see. May have to rethink this one.

Comment: It seems some other parts of the file is adding those blank lines. Above `<?php` tag there are few blank lines. But those are not like 300 lines. Try `var_dump($returnMessage);`. This will show whether base64_encode really prepends spaces or new lines. I believe not thought.

Comment: Also note you can always trim any spaces or new lines. Like `trim($returnMessage);`

Comment: OK. I printed both var_dump and the string on its on. The sting on its own had the white space but the var_dump returned the full string. how do I grab this?

Comment: $pdf_data it contained the full sting i required. Just looking though stackoverflow to see how to grab the sting without the numbers with brackets

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing error reporting, and the odd check for failure wouldn't hurt either. This should help. :)

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
$pdf_data = file_get_contents('test.pdf');

if( ! $pdf_data) {
    print 'Could not read file';
    exit;
}

$pdf_data = base64_encode($pdf_data);
print $pdf_data;
```

Comment: OK thanks for the code. For some reason the print data has a lot of white blank space before it. I was expecting a screen full of code instead got one line with aleast 300 blank characters. Is this normal?